# NSURLConnectionDownload suggestion

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm doing some experiment with the Foundation networking API and I'm trying to download files.
So I've created an `NSURLRequest`:

```
NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mysite.it/something.something"]];
```

Now I have a problem NSURLConnectionDownload.I have to implement this method

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didWriteData:(long long)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(long long)totalBytesWritten expectedTotalBytes:(long long)expectedTotalBytes
```

At connection I created a NSURLConnection object but I don't know which methods I must implement... Any suggestion?

Comment: See [this doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html).

Comment: When you say `NSURLConnectionDownload`, did you mean `NSURLDownload`? That's Mac OS X only. In iOS, you'd use `NSURLConnection` and then implement the [`NSURLConnectionDataDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html) methods as ana said or as outlined in the document Adam referenced.

Answer (score 0):

If you use
 `NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];` you'll probably want to implement 3 methods:

```
  - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data;
  - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error;
  - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection;
```

and maybe

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response;
```

I recommend you to take a look here : https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html .Hope it helpes!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice first comment.